# Auto scrolling on existing website

Tags: javascript, html

So i have some code that makes the web page automatically scroll across horizontally which works when i create the webpage, however when i attempt to open an existing webpage and then run the script nothing happens, can someone please explain what i need to do, i just want to be able to open the script, for it to then open the webpage and start scrolling back and forth, it's for displaying different work item on a canban board if that helps.

This is the what i have so far:

```js
<script>
window.open("https://www.bbc.co.uk/news");


var scrollWanted = true;
var scrollbarPosition = 0;
var pageWidth = getWidth();

function scrollWin() 
{
 var scrollDirection = 'Right';
 var pageWidth = getWidth();
 scrollWanted = true;
 

 function f() 
 {
  if(scrollWanted)
  {
   if(scrollbarPosition == 0)
   {
    scrollDirection = 'Right'
   }
   
   if(scrollbarPosition == 100)
   {

    scrollDirection = 'Left';
   }
   
   if(scrollDirection == 'Right')
   {
    window.scrollTo(window.scrollX + 1, 0);    
    scrollbarPosition++;     
   }
   
   if(scrollDirection == 'Left')
   {
    window.scrollTo(window.scrollX - 1, 0);    
    scrollbarPosition--;     
   }
      
   setTimeout( f, 30 );
   
   
   //Refresh
   //if( scrollX == 50 )
   //{
   // window.scrollTo(0,0);
   // location.reload();
   // 
   // setTimeout( f, 3000 );
   // scrollWin();
   //}
  }
 }
 f();
 

  
}

function getWidth() {
  return Math.max(
    document.body.scrollWidth,
    document.documentElement.scrollWidth,
    document.body.offsetWidth,
    document.documentElement.offsetWidth,
    document.documentElement.clientWidth
  );
}
</script>
```

I know that the BBC website doesn't extend horizontally but i can't think of any websites that do atm.

Thank you!
Kyle.

Comment: What do you expect to happen when you run this on a webpage that doesn't extend horizontally? I would expect nothing to happen..

Comment: "message": "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <",

your actually using html not JS here

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I understand your issue, you want to open some website `example.com` via javascript, content of which can be horizontally scrolled.

### Solution:

You need to assign the newly opened window to a variable, so that you can manipulate it after opening.

```
var newWindow = window.open('http://example.com');
```

For manipulation, use this `newWindow` variable as a `window` object like this:

```
newWindow.scrollTo(newWindow.scrollX + 1, 0);
```

Also, your `getWidth()` function needs to be changed like this:

```
function getWidth(win) {
  return Math.max(
    win.document.body.scrollWidth,
    win.document.documentElement.scrollWidth,
    win.document.body.offsetWidth,
    win.document.documentElement.offsetWidth,
    win.document.documentElement.clientWidth
  );
}
```

As you can guess, the `scrollWin()` function needs to be changed in the same way.

### Note 1

If you open a window with a different domain than the javascript is running on, the `window` object returned by `window.open()` is **inaccesible**.

That said, if your javascript is loaded on a site like `yoursite.com`, and you open another domain like `var newWindow = window.open('http://example.com')`, you **cannot** access the `newWindow.document` object, or any property of that `window` object, i.e. your `getWidth()` function will fail, and so will `scrollWin()`.

For example, try the following code in console on this page:

```
var newWindow = window.open('http://google.com');
alert(newWindow.body.scrollWidth);
```

will raise the following error:

```
Uncaught DOMException: Blocked a frame with origin "https://stackoverflow.com" from accessing a cross-origin frame.
```

### Note 2

If you use it on the same domain as your site, you need to consider the following:

After `var newWindow = window.open('http://yoursite.com')`, if you **immediately** access it like `newWindow.document.documentElement.offsetWidth`, you may get unwanted results, because the content of the new window may **still be loading**.

So, an `if(newWindow.document.readyState === 'complete')` check may be helpful to run the scrolling code afterwards.

I have tried to be as clear as I could be, feel free to ask for any clarification.

Comment: Hi Jay, thank you for responding, i've only managed to get the time to try this, i've been trying to build it up piece by piece but even this doesn't seem to make the page scroll down:


<script>
var newWindow = window.open("https://www.bbc.co.uk/news");
if(newWindow.document.readyState == 'complete')
{
 newWindow.scrollTo(0, 1110); 
}
</script>

I've also tried to add a setTimeout to call a function holding the scrollTo function but that doesn't work either :/

Comment: @KyleMann did you read **Note 1** carefully? If you are doing this on a site other than `bbc.co.uk`, this **will not work**! Check your javascript console for the error message. I assume you are not developing a page of `bbc.co.uk` itself, are you?

Comment: Sorry i'm not sure what you mean as i've just started doing something like this, maybe i'm doing this wrong but all i have so far is a HTML document that i've been editing in notepad++ and all that i have in there so far is the code from my previous comment so that it opens the page and scrolls to a position, i'm not hosting the website i just want to be able to run this on an existing website. But after properly reading Note 1 maybe you can't do this, i thought that there was a way to inject code into an existing website, please let me know if i'm way off as i'm just a beginner! :)

Comment: You got it right, you **cannot** do this. This is a security feature in modern browsers. You cannot inject arbitrary code into webpages you don't have control of. The only way to overcome this would be to make yourself a browser that can turn this feature off.

Comment: Okay no problem, i'll have to think of something else to use, thank you for your advice Jay :)

Comment: @KyleMann you're welcome. Please accept my answer if it helped.